# What is efficient way to match words in string?

Tags: python

Example:

```
names = ['James John', 'Robert David', 'Paul' ... the list has 5K items]

text1 = 'I saw James today'
text2 = 'I saw James John today'
text3 = 'I met Paul'

is_name_in_text(text1,names)   # this returns false 'James' in not in list
is_name_in_text(text2,names)   # this returns 'James John'
is_name_in_text(text3,names)   # this return 'Paul'
```

`is_name_in_text()` searches if any of the name list is in text.

The easy way to do is to just check if the name is in the list by using `in` operator, but the list has 5,000 items, so it is not efficient. I can just split the text into words and check if the words are `in` the list, but this not going to work if you have more than one word matching. Line number 7 will fail in this case.

Comment: Do you already have a mechanism of pulling the names out of the phrases?

Comment: yes, I can make that change. It can also be in dictionary. `['James John' : 'James John']`

Comment: Nicely posed question.  Good job showing the test data.

Comment: I'm interested in the mechanism for pulling the names out of the phrases. Yes, once you have that you can just use a `set`, but how do you do it efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make *names* into a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and use the in-operator for fast O(1) lookup.

You can use a regex to parse out the possible names in a sentence:

```
>>> import re
>>> findnames = re.compile(r'([A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*)?)')
>>> def is_name_in_text(text, names):
        for possible_name in set(findnames.findall(text)):
            if possible_name in names:
                return possible_name
        return False

>>> names = set(['James John', 'Robert David', 'Paul'])
>>> is_name_in_text('I saw James today', names)
False
>>> is_name_in_text('I saw James John today', names)
'James John'
>>> is_name_in_text('I met Paul', names)
'Paul'
```

Comment: How do you use `in` to search for any of `set(['James John', 'Robert David', ...])` in `'I saw James John today'`?

Comment: Edited the answer to show a regex for capturing the names in the text input.

Comment: Here's a counterexample sentence for you: `"For John James, this does't work."`

Comment: ??? "John James" isn't in the sample data.  It looks like you've transposed the first and last names.

Comment: Sorry. `"For James John"`: The point is that your regexp matches `For James` and `John`, not `James John`.

Answer (score 2):

Build a regular expression with all the alternatives. This way you don't have to worry about somehow pulling the names out of the phrases beforehand.

```
import re
names_re = re.compile(r'\b' +
                      r'\b|\b'.join(re.escape(name) for name in names) +
                      r'\b')

print names_re.search('I saw James today')
```

Comment: That's a nice answer, though it does make for a rather large regex with 5000+ names :-)

Comment: Is that a problem? Compiling the regexp will take some time (I got a second for 15000+ names), but the searching is nearly instant.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Python's [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) in order to get good performance while using the in operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mechanism of pulling the names out of the phrases and don't need to worry about partial matches (the full name will always be in the string), you can use a set rather than a list.

Your code is exactly the same, with this addition at line 2:

```
names = set(names)
```

The `in` operation will now function much faster.